# Can not install software from ubuntu software center

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, dpkg, crash

Whenever I try to install software from the ubuntu software center, it gives me the following error after I enter my password:

```
Package operation failed
The installation or removal of a software package failed
OK
```

and if I try to install it a lot more times, a

```
▶Details
```

thing apears. When I click that, it gives me this:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0174' near line 0:
```

Also something that might be helpful is that I am running ubuntu through virtualbox and when my computer crashed (not the virtual one, but my mac one), I was running ubuntu in virtualbox, and ever since then I have had this problem. Anyone know why? Thanks.

EDIT:
I've tried again, and when I click details, the message changed:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0174' near line 0:
  EOF after field name `'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to reset you apt-get list's

- sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0174
- sudo dpkg --configure -a
- $ sudo -i
- # apt-get clean
- # cd /var/lib/apt
- # mv lists lists.old
- # mkdir -p lists/partial
- # apt-get clean
- # apt-key update
- # apt-get update

Comment: I did that, and when it finished, it said: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

When I do that, It gives me the same error I have been having for this whole time:
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0174' near line 0:
EOF after field name `'

Comment: Ran these two commands in terminal (CTRL+ALT+T):

 - sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0174
 - sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: updated answer to remove var/lib/dpkg/updates/0174